# How to make sure only a single checkbox remains checked out of many?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have some HTML with checkboxes (using radio buttons is not convenient due to the library that generates the HTML - to add detail, I'd need to either hack one myself outside of the library or find an unconventional way to make the library work for me).

I need to simulate radio button functionality, in particular - when checking a single box out of many, all other boxes should be unchecked.

I am trying to uncheck all boxes, and then check the one that I clicked.  My jQuery/JS is failing.  Can you help?

```js
$(function() {
  //check first box
  $("input.duty:first").attr("checked", "true");

  //clicking unchecked box should check that box
  //unchecks all others
  $(".duty").on('click', function(event) {
    $("input.duty").attr("checked", "false");
    $(this).prop("checked", true);
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="casePointsFieldset">
  <fieldset class="casePointFieldset">
    <div>
      <label><span>Duty:</span>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="casePoints[0][isDutyPoint]" class="duty" value="0"></label>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="casePointFieldset">

    <div>
      <label><span>Duty:</span>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="casePoints[1][isDutyPoint]" class="duty" value="0"></label>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="casePointFieldset">
    <div>
      <label><span>Duty:</span>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="casePoints[2][isDutyPoint]" class="duty" value="0"></label>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use `.prop` in all cases rather than mix `.prop`/`.attr`.
- use `true` and `false` rather than strings.

Updated snippet:

```js
$(function() {
  //check first box
  $("input.duty:first").prop("checked", true);

  //clicking unchecked box should check that box
  //unchecks all others
  $(".duty").on('click', function(event) {
    $("input.duty").prop("checked", false);
    $(this).prop("checked", true);
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="casePointsFieldset">
  <fieldset class="casePointFieldset">
    <div>
      <label><span>Duty:</span>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="casePoints[0][isDutyPoint]" class="duty" value="0"></label>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="casePointFieldset">

    <div>
      <label><span>Duty:</span>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="casePoints[1][isDutyPoint]" class="duty" value="0"></label>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="casePointFieldset">
    <div>
      <label><span>Duty:</span>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="casePoints[2][isDutyPoint]" class="duty" value="0"></label>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: Just FYI you can't deselect a checkbox with this logic. That may suit the OP thgouh, if they want to mimic radio button behaviour

Comment: that does suit me to where I can't deselect it.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to achieve this is to call `prop('checked', false)` on all the other checkboxes when any one of them is clicked, like this:

```js
$(".duty").first().prop('checked', true).end().on('click', function(event) {
  $('.duty').not(this).prop('checked', false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="casePointsFieldset">
  <fieldset class="casePointFieldset">
    <div>
      <label>
        <span>Duty:</span>
        <input type="checkbox" name="casePoints[0][isDutyPoint]" class="duty" value="0">
      </label>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="casePointFieldset">
    <div>
      <label>
        <span>Duty:</span>
        <input type="checkbox" name="casePoints[1][isDutyPoint]" class="duty" value="0">
      </label>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="casePointFieldset">
    <div>
      <label>
        <span>Duty:</span>
        <input type="checkbox" name="casePoints[2][isDutyPoint]" class="duty" value="0">
      </label>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: I was just going to ask .. is there a simple way to make sure you can't unselect the (single) checkbox? aka leave it selected?  I am trying `$('.duty').is(this).prop('checked', true);` and it's not doing it

Comment: There is - use the logic that @freedomn-m posted in his answer

Answer (score 0):

If you only ever want one checkbox, you should consider radio buttons.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/radio

This should fit the use case better. Let me know if you need any help with implementation.

I know you say radios are hard because of your use case, but you should seriously consider extending your library with functionality for radio buttons.  It is more correct from HTML standpoint as well as form a UI/UX standpoint.

Comment: Whilst I agree, the OP did state: `using radio buttons is not convenient due to the library that generates the HTML`

Comment: It makes no sense to go with checkboxes, both from a UI standpoint and a standards standpoint.  They should extend their library if it's an issue. Thanks for the downvote though.

Comment: Well they came in at the same time so it seemed like it did, my apologies.

Comment: I agree with this answer; it's what I would have posted. Convenience for the programmer should never outweigh consistency in the user interface, Occam's razor, KISS, the principle of least astonishment and general user friendliness.

Comment: thanks. in my case.. 3-4 lines of JS/jQuery that does the job is better than figuring out a project of how to twist the library towards my need. I can probably look into the library way of doing it, but JS way is so much better for me right now that it works.  If I find a way to hack `Zend\Form` to span a `Radio` button across different fieldsets, I'd use the radio button.  Otherwise, it creates a `Fieldset` that does not span... aka I'd have to hack one myself via HTML, or put some serious thought into how to hack the library so it does what I need.

Comment: Might be your chance to make an open source contribution @dennis :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the checked-property to the boolean `false`, not to the string `"false"`.

Using the string will be interpreted as `true`.

```
$("input.duty").attr("checked", false);
```